# SSRS: bracketed identifier missing closing

Tags: reporting-services

Let me preface this that I am not a developer and I don't normally work in SSRS.

I am receiving `Textbox16.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]` contains an error:

```
[BC30034] Bracketed identifier is missing closing ']'.
```

The expression in Textbox16 is

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Pallets.Value=0,[Sum(NumUnits)]*ReportItems!FloorLocations.Value,[Sum(NumUnits)]*ReportItems!Pallets.Value)
```

I tried just `=[Sum(NumUnits)]*ReportItems!FloorLocations.Value` and get the same error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I actually tried something different and used the ReportItem name that corresponds to [Sum(NumUnits)]. No more error.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS is expecting an identifier name between the `[` and `]`, not an expression. Instead of `[Sum(NumUnits)]` you should use `Sum([NumUnits])`, putting only the identifier name in the brackets and then summing that.

Alternatively, if NumUnits is a field, just reference it from the Fields collection:

```
Sum(Fields!NumUnits.Value)
```